# Как в numpy получить array из списка массивов?

Tags: python, циклы, numpy

У меня есть список массивов `array`, из которого надо выбрать первый из массивов:

```
[array([0.0016, 0.5859, 0.2212, 0.1422, 0.0491]),
 array([ 0.5843, -0.3647, -0.079 , -0.0931]),
 array([-0.949 ,  0.2857, -0.0141]),
 array([ 1.2347, -0.2998]),
 array([-1.5345])]
```

Однако если я выбираю код с нулевым элементом, то на выходе вижу все нулевые элементы каждого массива `array`:

```
for elen in result:
    print(elen[0])
```

```
# ВЫВОД:
0.0016
0.5842999999999999
-0.949
1.2347000000000001
-1.5345000000000002
```

Мне же надо получить `array([0.0016, 0.5859, 0.2212, 0.1422, 0.0491])`

Comment: Потому что циклом вы перебираете весь список, потому в elen находится просто массив array, а elen[0] дает вам нулевой элемент этого массива, ну и так по списку. Сделайте вместо цикла просто print(result[0])

Comment: @Dafter, благодарю - сработало. Результат достигнут

Comment: Отлично, тогда оформил как ответ

Comment: Если всё это и снаружи тоже взять в numpy.array, то можно вообще просто: `result[:,0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи цикла `for elen in result:` вы проходитесь по каждому `array` в списке, после чего выводите на экран нулевой элемент каждого из `array`'ев.

Для вывода на экран только первого `array` замените цикл на:

```
print(result[0])
```